# APS.NET core 2.2 Entity framework db migration looking for primary key

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration, data-access-layer

I am trying to run DB migration on my DAL project but receiving an error that my entity does not have key defined which has ?! could anyone help, please.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, please post your code and not an image.

Entity Framework will work from properties defined in your model, and the Id property is set up by convention. However you need to have the Id set up as a property for it to work correctly, and right now you have it as a field.

Change

`public int Id;` to `public int Id { get; set; }` and try again and you should be in business.

Comment: Thank you. Copy and paste are sometimes problematic. I copied that property from somewhere else and did not pay attention to it.